# Run automation test in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I am newbie about lambda service
I am using dockerfile to copy automation test source code.
Is it possible to run cmd "poetry run pytest test/" in def lambda_handler(event, context):?

Or replace CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"] in dockerfile by cmd 'poetry run pytest test/'

Comment: Technically you can run whatever you want inside your lambda, but practically that is not really what Lambda is supposed to be used for. You could instead use e.g. codebuild for that or just a fargate task.